# What's the limit of Zatanna's magic?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-dark

Is there a limit to Zatanna's magic? It seems that the sentence spoken by Zatanna in reverse pronounce order will come to true. This implies that Zatanna is extremely powerful, or, nearly omnipotent.

However, obviously, Zatanna didn't solve all the problems in DC universe by saying "no more villains". What's the limit of Zatanna's magic? For example, if Zatanna said "move the Mars out of the solar system", will it be realized?

Comment: yeah, because "no more villains" wouldn't work; she's got to say "*on erom snialliv*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a concrete answer to this question. Any limits she does have is largely dependent on the writer, and likely to change from writer to writer.

The only limit I've ever seen stated is in Young Justice where she states she's less powerful than Doctor Fate, but has more flexibility with her spells since Fate is an agent of pure order and she's human, which allows her to have some spell effects that Fate does not.

Her main limit is that she must speak the words of her spell, so anything that can silence her will render her spell-casting useless.

Comment: I believe *Young Justice* also has a scene or two where she indicates that she's in the process of learning new magical effects. I think the implication is that it's not *just* about shouting out a random backwards sentence; she also has some non-verbal component of her magic which serves as a limiting factor.